# how to print Multiple String arrays output in a single line

Tags: java, arrays, printing

I have 3 String arrays. 
I want to print the all the 3 single arrays one after another in java.
So like my 2 arrays look like-

```
  o  
 ooo 
ooooo
 ooo 
  o  

  o o
ooooo
 ooo 
ooooo
 o oo
```

I want to print each element of the array one after another (right next to eachother)

Current code result-

```
  o  
 ooo 
ooooo
 ooo 
  o  
  o o
ooooo
 ooo 
ooooo
 o oo
 o o 
 ooo 
ooooo
 ooo 
  o
```

So expected output

```
  o  o o o  o  
 ooo ooooo oooo
ooooo ooo oooo 
 ooo ooooo oooo
```

The output above may differ from inputs, but its just the sample I am showing . This is how I am expecting to print.

current code-

```
    String[] tp1 = { "  o  ", " ooo ", "ooooo", " ooo ", "  o  " };
    String[] tp2 = { "  o o", "ooooo", " ooo ", "ooooo", " o oo" };
    String[] tp3 = { " o o ", " ooo ", "ooooo", " ooo ", "  o  " };
    List<String[]> values = new ArrayList<>();
    values.add(tp1);
    values.add(tp2);
    values.add(tp3);
    for (String[] strings : values) {
        String output = "";
        for (String string : strings) {
            output += string;
            output += "\n";
        }
        System.out.print(output);
    }
```

Comment: use `System.out.println`

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What is the result of your current code? Could you give us an example of how the correct output would be? Or is that what the first code block is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invert your for loops. And hence you cannot you the `for each` syntax.

Use,

```
for (int i = 0; i < tp1.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < values.size(); j++) {
        System.out.print(values.get(j)[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8 you can use the new forEach and a Lambda like this:

```
        values.forEach(value -> {
            Arrays.asList(value).forEach(array -> System.out.print(array));
            System.out.println();
        });
```

which results in

```
  o   ooo ooooo ooo   o  
  o oooooo ooo ooooo o oo
 o o  ooo ooooo ooo   o
```

If you realy want this:

```
  o    o o o o 
 ooo ooooo ooo 
ooooo ooo ooooo
 ooo ooooo ooo 
  o   o oo  o
```

You can do this like so:

```
    for (int i=0; i<tp1.length; i++) {
        final int j = i;
        values.forEach(value -> System.out.print(value[j]));
        System.out.println();
    };
```

But then I would recommend you to flip the list and or the arrays. Since it is not clear if all arrays tp1..3 will have the same length. For example this way:

```
        String[] tp1 = { "  o  ", "  o o", " o o "};
        String[] tp2 = { " ooo ", "ooooo", " ooo "};
        String[] tp3 = { "ooooo", " ooo ", "ooooo" };
        String[] tp4 = { "  o  ", " o oo" , "  o  " };

        ArrayList<String[]> values = new ArrayList<>();
        values.add(tp1);
        values.add(tp2);
        values.add(tp3);
        values.add(tp4);

        values.forEach(value -> {
            Arrays.asList(value).forEach(array -> System.out.print(array));
            System.out.println();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

To get that output you don't require the `values` variable. You have to output the 1st string of all the arrays in a single line so change your `for` loop to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println(tp1[i]+tp2[i]+tp3[i]);
}
```

I feel this should solve your problem.